# How to list all keg only formulas installed?

Tags: homebrew

I want to list all keg-only formulas installed on a machine. Could anybody show me a single command that can do this job? I haven't find a solution to do this task.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success running this command to get formulas that are installed as `keg-only`:

`[$]> brew info --installed --json=v1 | jq 'map(select(.keg_only == true)) | map(.name)'`

References:

https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/26903

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/26165